# Error accessing Stream REST Api using JWT

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to use JWT token to access a Stream feed but it is returning 404 everytime.

Token header:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

Token payload:

```
{
  "resource": "feed",
  "action": "read"
}
```

The token was generated using the [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) library and signed using the secret provided in my account dashboard. I also validated it on jwt.io and it was a valid token

Url

```
GET: https://api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/notification/666?api-key=...
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZXNvdXJjZSI6ImZlZWQiLCJhY3Rpb24iOiJyZWFkIn0.MUZHXQg0UD6jFpCZN5Mn1e7wwys_1qYuVtfBKtHL8QU
```

Response

```
{
    "exception": "GetStreamAPI404",
    "detail": "sorry you've hit a 404"
}
```

Am I missing something here? Can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform correct permission checking, you need to include the `feed_id` field in your token payload. The value of the field must be the same as the feed that you are trying to read and be in the form of `${feed_group}:${feed_id}`.

For instance, the payload for the request in your question (https://api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/notification/666?api-key=) should be:

```
{
  "resource": "feed",
  "action": "read",
  "feed_id": "notification:666"
}
```

Note: API URLs must end with a trailing slash (eg. /api/v1.0/feed/notification/666/?api_key=...)

Auth HTTP headers:

**Authorization** must only contain the JWT token

**stream-auth-type** must be sent with the value jwt

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had tried with feed_id as well but that was also giving an error. But adding the trailing / made it work. Now I am getting this message: "url signature missing or invalid"